# How to get only conflicts using git diff between two branches

Tags: git

I have a branch with a new feature that I don't want to merge yet, just resolve the conflicts.

Is there a way to get the conflicts without actually merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge master into the branch you are developing the feature on.

ie.

```
git checkout FEATURE_BRANCH
git merge master
```

resolve conflicts, commit

Now when you merge back to master the conflicts will already be resolved

Comment: @dan-baker, another way to go would be to `git rebase` your work (remember that it was invented precisely for this -- to "forward-port" a set of commits onto their *updated* base).  You will have to deal with conflicts during the rebase but, again, when you're about to merge your work back to `master`, it will merge cleanly.  Whether to merge (re-intergate) or rebase (forward-port) depends on your workflow preference.